# SQL Server Secure and Unsecure Traffic Configuration Help

Tags: sql-server, ssl, configuration-manager

I have a SQL Server 2017 instance that I have configured to listen on multiple ports 1433 and 1234. I would like to know if its possible to have one port (1234) accept **only** secure connections while the default port accept both?

I have already set up the instance, verified both ports are working, and installed the certificate but it seems my only option is to force SSL for the entire instance in config manager. Am I missing something? All help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to know why you wouldn't just force encryption always.

Comment: @Charlieface sadly there are some tightly coupled legacy applications that do not support encrypted connections. my initial hope was we could secure one port and leave the other port available to accept both secure and non-secure connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

No. "Force Encryption" is an instance-wide setting.